# What's wrong in syntax unable to fetch the data.(MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("7df78ad8902c"),
   "title": "MongoDB Overview", 
   "description": "MongoDB is no sql database",
   "by": "school",
   "url": "http://www.school.com",
   "tags": ["mongodb", "database", "NoSQL"],
   "likes": "100"
}
```

//My code to get value.

```
db.mycollection.find({"likes": {$lt:2000}}).pretty()
```

//Giving error

> SyntaxError invalid property id @(shell) :1:32

//My another code

```
db.mycollection.find({$and:[{"by":"school"},{"title": "MongoDB Overview"}]}).pretty()
```

//Giving this error

> SyntaxError invalid property id @(shell) :1:22

I am new to mongoDB so help me to know where is error and how to resolve.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pass id as string: `"_id": ObjectId("7df78ad8902c"),`

Comment: do you have the document in the collection? only the fetch is giving error?

Comment: Yes, only fetch is giving error@Saravana

Answer (score 0):

Well, *insert* for the document you've posted also gives an error because of the way you create _id as @skm already mentioned. Check [the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/index.html) to understand how to do it or omit altogether and _id will be created automatically during *insert*. The first *find* runs without errors but finds nothing because `likes` attribute is set to string value `"100"` and you try to find documents where `likes` is less than `2000` integer. The second *find* actually finds the document.